# CheckBox checked become unchecked after sorting or paging (not GridView)

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a checkbox in aspx form page, external to a GridView.

If I checked this checkbox executed one query that populated this gridview and update your rows.

This Gridview is paginated and when I change page returns to initial GridView rows and lost the selection in checkbox.

Is there a way to keep checked after sorting and paging?

Thanks.

**Edit #1**

My code below.

When checkbox is checked in **BindData();** is executed a different query to the initial.

```
int ck = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}


protected void ddlPages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvrPager = gvProducts.BottomPagerRow;
    DropDownList ddlPages = (DropDownList)gvrPager.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlPages");

    gvProducts.PageIndex = ddlPages.SelectedIndex;
    BindData();
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    gvProducts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindData();
}

protected void Paginate(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int intCurIndex = gvProducts.PageIndex;

    switch (e.CommandArgument.ToString().ToLower())
    {
        case "First":
            gvProducts.PageIndex = 0;
            break;
        case "Prev":
            gvProducts.PageIndex = intCurIndex - 1;
            break;
        case "Next":
            gvProducts.PageIndex = intCurIndex + 1;
            break;
        case "Last":
            gvProducts.PageIndex = gvProducts.PageCount - 1;
            break;
    }
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "money")) > 100000)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AntiqueWhite;
        }
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)(e.Row.FindControl("ddlpages"));
        Label lblPageCount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPageCount");

        if (lblPageCount != null)
            lblPageCount.Text = gvProducts.PageCount.ToString();

        for (int i = 1; i <= gvProducts.PageCount; i++)
        {
            ddl.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        ddl.SelectedIndex = gvProducts.PageIndex;

        if (gvProducts.PageIndex == 0)
        {
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton1")).Visible = false;
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton2")).Visible = false;
        }

        if (gvProducts.PageIndex + 1 == gvProducts.PageCount)
        {
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton3")).Visible = false;
            ((ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("ImageButton4")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
}


protected void chkLinked_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        try
        {
            if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
            {
                ck = 1;
                BindData();
            }
            else
            {
                ck = 0;
                BindData();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

**Edit #2**

```
private DataSet RetrieveProducts()
{
    if (ViewState["Products"] != null)
        return (DataSet)ViewState["Products"];

        if (ck > 0)
        {
            sql = @" SELECT * FROM doTable Where money > 100000; ";
        }
        else
        {
            sql = @" SELECT * FROM doTable; ";
        }

    DataSet dsProducts = new DataSet();

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))

            OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dsProducts);
        }
    }

    return dsProducts;
}


private void BindData()
{
    gvProducts.DataSource = RetrieveProducts();
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: could you post your code? I can imagine few situations that this case can happen, but if you post your code, people can give you a straight answer :)

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: Most probably you are assigning value to that check box in  IsPostBack event in page load.

Comment: Okay thank you; I have added in my first question the used code.

Comment: can you please post definition of BindData..especially are you doing anything with check box  or variable ck in binddata function.

Comment: @SagarShirke: Okay in Edit # 2 on my first question, thank you.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq..Is EnableViewState property of checkbox is false??

Comment: @SagarShirke I think so

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq..Can you please set EnableViewState=true for this checkbox and check again..It should not be false (by default its value is true)

Comment: @SagarShirke I am sorry Sir ... I don't understand ...

Comment: @SagarShirke I am sorry Sir ... I don't understand ... I have set EnableViewState="true" in checkbox but I have the same problem ...

Comment: <asp:CheckBox ID="chkLinked" runat="server"  EnableViewState="true"/>.. I was saying this option

Comment: @SagarShirke Yes Sir, I have tried now working, thank you ... but for closed the question?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq..If that solved your problem then I have added this as answer..If you want in future if any body wants same answer easily then you can accept it as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible reason can be Viewstate is not enabled for the check box that is why it is not preserving the state.To enable it you can use EnableViewState property of checkbox.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkLinked" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"/>.
```